# How to a dynamic row in a table using Razor view in MVC4?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-table

I have a table in the razor view and this table contain some Html controls like below:-

```
  <table style="text-align: center; width: 680px; background-color: White;" rules="all" id="tableId">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 20px;"></td>
                    <td>
                        <label>
                            Campaign Name</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>
                            Valid Date From</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>
                            Valid Date To</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>
                            Is Active</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>
                            ContractPDF</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>
                            Browse Contract</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customer_ID)
                    </td>
                    <td class="trBorder">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer_Name)
                    </td>
                    <td class="trBorder">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ValidFrom, new { @class = "datepicker" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ValidTo, new { @class = "datepicker" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBox("gridChkCampaignIsActive", m => m.IsActive)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContractDocumentPath)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Browse", "FileUpload")
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

**Add Customer button**

`<input type="button" value="Add Customer" name="btnAddCustomer" id="btnAddCustomer" style="margin-left: 20px;"/>`

My problem is that I want this table like a grid control and when I click on `"Add Customer"` button, a blank row will be added in the grid control.

please Help me!

Any Help Will be Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Its Too simple assign each element an id to it and in  access values and then populate a table

like

```
@Html.TextForFor(m=>m.name, new {@class="form-control", id="name"})
    //then dynamically table to be populated via javascript
     <table id="tbl">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></thead>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Add Customer" name="btnAddCustomer" id="btnAddCustomer" style="margin-left: 20px;"/>
    //assume that u have assign id to text boxes like a, b, c, and ,so on..
    <script>
    $.(#btnAddCustomer).click(function () {
     var pc = $("#pcode").val();
            var p = $("#a").val();
            var q = $("#b").val();
            var e = $("#c").val();
            var rows = '';
            rows += "<tr>"
            rows += "<td>" + p + "</td>"
            rows += "<td>" + q + "</td>"
            rows += "<td>" + r + "</td>"       
            rows += "</tr>";
            $("#tbl tbody").append(rows);

    })
    </script>
```